# Flutter TabBarView inside CustomScrollView - Unresponsive content and scrolling issues

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I'm trying to implement a Flutter app with a `TabBarView` inside a `CustomScrollView` and below `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar`, where each tab has scrollable content. However, I'm facing some issues with unresponsive content and scrolling behavior.

I tried to use `NestedScrollView` and `SliverOverlapObserver` but it did not work

Example vide can be found here:
https://github.com/theiskaa/dotfiles/assets/59066341/934acc26-1824-4450-877e-3f264b999f2f

Answer (score -1):

Add Widget [SliverFillRemaining](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html) after CupertinoSliverNavigationBar inside
the CustomScrollView.

SliverFillRemaining will take the remaining scrolling area and handle it. Now pass the TabBarView as the child for SliverFillRemaining.

Refer to the below code, for a sample implementation.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

///
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  /// base constructor
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
            leading: Icon(Icons.person_2),
            largeTitle: Text('Title'),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.add_box),
          ),

          //
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: [
                _buildTempList(15),
                _buildTempList(5),
                _buildTempList(25),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTempList(int itemCount) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: itemCount,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => CupertinoListTile(
        title: Text('This is $index'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```